# How to deploy a plugin to Heroku

Tags: php, wordpress, git, heroku, deployment

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin and I'm trying to figure out how I can deploy it to Heroku.

The plugin is version controlled with git, but it needs to be installed in a site in order to run/test. When I try to deploy the entire site using git, only the site gets deployed, but the nested git directory (for my plugin) is ignored. I considered setting it up as a git submodule, but according to the Heroku docs that won't work either.

What do I do? Surely there must be a way to deploy to Heroku when you're git repository doesn't live in the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend deploying Wordpress to Heroku, but it turns out the documentation I was reading was old. Heroku will install git submodules, so the way to do it is to make your project a submodule and configure the git project in the document root. Warning: Git submodules suck.